# Single sign on from SharePoint to another asp.net web application

Tags: sharepoint, single-sign-on

I have a scenario where I want to get the single sign on experience between SharePoint and another ASP.NET website.  They are both on same domain and both using windows authentication.  Both website have anonymous authentication turned off and windows authentication turned on.  Can anyone please help for the following scenario?

1. User go to SharePoint 2010 website
2. Login to SharePoint by entering windows username and password to landing login page
3. SharePoint 2010 contains iframed webpart which go to another asp.net website on same domain  (different port number)
4. **User should be able to access the another asp.net website without login**

My problem is during step 4 where user have to enter the windows credential again to login to asp.net website.  How can I resolve this issue?

Thanks,

SJ

Comment: If its windows authentication , whey is he entering username/password in Sharepoint site?

Comment: Please check this question 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2998964/sharepoint-2010-two-web-applications-single-sign-on-do-i-need-claims-bas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows authentication is not automatically passed between applications. Since you choose to iframe the other site you will need to separately login to it.

I find it a bit odd that your users dont get automatically logged in, but then you maybe dont have domain login on your computers.

However this can be automated a bit with impersonation, check this thread http://forums.asp.net/t/304484.aspx